# Como alterar objeto do Json?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Estou tentando alterar o valor desse objeto/propriedade porem retorna o erro de underfined ate mesmo quando dou console.log, queria entender porque não consigo chegar nele.
- HTML

```
<li v-for="item in items">
      {{item.name}} - {{item.Qtd}}
       <input type="button" value="+" @click="AdicionarQtd()">
       <input type="button" value="Remover Item" @click="removerItem">
       <span v-if="!(item.Qtd >0)">Fora de estoque</span>
     </li>
```

-Método

```
 AdicionarQtd: function(item){
                this.item.Qtd+=1;
            }
```

Json

```
items: [{
            name:'caneta',
            Qtd:5,
        }],
```

Comment: No método você não passou o `item` e na função se chamou variável do seu escopo. Não vai dar certo realmente

Answer (score 0):

No seu código, não foi especificado qual item vai sofrer alteração na `Qtd` e na exclusão também não foi passado o item que deve ser excluido, exemplo:

```
<input type="button" value="+" @click="AdicionarQtd(item)">
<input type="button" value="Remover Item" @click="removerItem(item)">
```

observe que nos dois `input type button` no nas função é passado o item da coleção,  e com isso te auxiliar nas alterações individuais e exclusão sumária do item.

***Código:***

```js
new Vue({
      el: "#lista",
      data: function() {
        return {
          items: [{
              name: 'caneta',
              Qtd: 0
            },
            {
              name: 'lapis',
              Qtd: 2
            },
            {
              name: 'borracha',
              Qtd: 3
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      methods: {
        AdicionarQtd: function(item) {
          item.Qtd++;
        },
        removerItem: function(item) {
          const index = this.items.indexOf(item);
          this.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="lista">
  <li v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="index">
    {{item.name}} - {{item.Qtd}}
    <input type="button" value="+" @click="AdicionarQtd(item)">
    <input type="button" value="Remover Item" @click="removerItem(item)">
    <span v-if="(item.Qtd === 0)">Fora de estoque</span>
  </li>
</div>
```